# How to solve this non-linear 1st order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following first order differential equation:
$$ g'(R)=-2 \sqrt{R^2-g(R)}+2 R$$

By direct substitution it can be verified that an obvious solution is $$g(R)=R^2.$$

However, when doing the transformation $y(R)=R^2-g(R)$, we get 
$$y'(R)=2 \sqrt{y(R)} $$
which is separable and gives (for some constant $C$):
$$\int \frac{dy}{2y^{1/2}}=R+C $$
or
$$y^{1/2}= R+C,\\
y=(R+C)^2.$$
Remembering that $y(R)=R^2-g(R)$ we finally get $$ g(R)= -C^2-2C R .$$

I also tried solving it with [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214195/why-does-dsolve-fail-in-this-first-order-differential-equation), but it also misses the other solution.

**So, my question is where did the obvious solution $g(R)=R^2$ go?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to check the case where $y=0$ in solving $y'=2\sqrt y$. When you solve this differential equation generally you implicitly assumed $y\ne0$ (because you have a divison by $\sqrt y$ in the integral form).

Comment: Oh, ok I see. For $y \neq 0$ we get the aforementioned solution, while for $y=0$ we get $g=R^2$ as expected. Then both branches of the solution for $g(R)$ would be valid?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum Yes.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! I'm still a bit puzzled why Mathematica doesn't consider this case, so I'll update my question at the Mathematica stack with the new info. Again thanks!